# Adding a class instance property from a list to a combobox item in C# WFA

Tags: c#

I have a database of teas in a file, I make a new instance of the Tea class with properties like Name, Price, Flavor etc for each tea in the database from the file and place each one of the Tea type objects in a `List<Tea>`.
Now I need to transfer the names of the teas in a ComboBox and I can't figure it out, with a `foreach` probably, am I right? But how? Please help! I am probably doing something wrong with the class, see my class code (it's in Czech, don't freak out):

```
class Caj
{

    public static string Nazev
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public static string ZemePuvodu
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public static string Detail
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public static string BarvaNalevu
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public static string Chut
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static int Cena
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static int DobaLouhovani
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static int PocetLzicek
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static string Nalevy
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static int TeplotaVody
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Caj(string nazev, string zemePuvodu, string detail, string barvaNalevu, string chut, int cena, int dobaLouhovani, int pocetLzicek, string nalevy, int teplotaVody)
    {
        Nazev = nazev;
        ZemePuvodu = zemePuvodu;
        Detail = detail;
        BarvaNalevu = barvaNalevu;
        Chut = chut;
        Cena = cena;
        DobaLouhovani = dobaLouhovani;
        PocetLzicek = pocetLzicek;
        Nalevy = nalevy;
        TeplotaVody = teplotaVody;
    }
}
```

And this is my Form code for now:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Zika_projekt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static string cesta = "databaze.txt";
        static int pocetCaju = File.ReadAllLines(cesta).Length;

        private static List<Caj> databaze = new List<Caj>();


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (File.Exists(cesta))
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(cesta, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
                cbNazevCaje.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < pocetCaju; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < i;)
                    {
                        sr.ReadLine();
                    }
                    string[] caj = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
                    Caj novyCaj = new Caj(caj[0], caj[1], caj[2], caj[3], caj[4], Convert.ToInt32(caj[5]), Convert.ToInt32(caj[6]), Convert.ToInt32(caj[7]), caj[8], Convert.ToInt32(caj[9]));
                    cbNazevCaje.Items.Add(novyCaj.);
                    databaze.Add(novyCaj);
                }
                sr.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataSource` property of the combobox:

```
cbNazevCaje.DataSource = databaze;
cbNazevCaje.DisplayMember = "Nazev";  // I'm guessing Nazev is Czech for Name?
```

Comment: Yes, Nazev is Czech for Name ;)
But that actually didn't work :/
My combobox is now full of the object type name `Zika_projek.Caj`